# Какой цикл нужен для внесения данных из потока ввода в конец односвязного списка?

Tags: pascal

Я не так давно познакомился с указателями в паскале и с односвязными списками.

С помощью какого цикла вводить данные из стандартного потока ввода в начало односвязного списка я понял.

А вот какой цикл нужен для внесения данных из потока ввода в конец такого списка я почему-то понять не могу. Вот в голове не могу представить картину и всё.

Пожалуйста, покажите этот цикл и я сразу пойму. Либо объясните получше. Если изначально список пустой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо того, чтобы делать, как в начале

```
 NewElement^.Next := Head;
 Head := NewElement;
```

делаете

```
 NewElement^.Next := Nil; // если этого не делается при создании нового узла
 Tail^.Next := NewElement;
 Tail := NewElement;
```

при условии, что у вас хранится указатель на конечный узел. Если этого нет, то проходите по списку

```
Tail := Head;
while Tail^.Next <> Nil do
   Tail := Tail^.Next;
```

пока не найдёте последний узел (`Next = Nil`) и используете его так, как показано выше.

Comment: Чтоб как в начале - основной список нулевой. Создаётся новый внутри цикла чтения до ситуации конца файла. В новый помещается значение прочитанное и в указатель на следующий помещается основной нулевой, потом основной = новый. И так по новой. Я делал так. А понять как сделать наоборот не укладывается почему-то :((

Comment: Я ж написал....

Comment: Я не слишком понял ваш ответ, но спасибо за попытку)) Я оставил ответ на свой вопрос. Прокомментируйте его, пожалуйста, то же самое ли вы имели ввиду или нет ) Теперь я буду разбираться как это работает :D

Comment: если обозначено tail вместо last, то всё, ничего не понятно?

Comment: то что написано после ДЕЛАЕТЕ в вашем ответе, вот там я ничего не понял...

Answer (score 0):

В общем, вот правильное решение... С помощью книги.

```
program zadacha2;
type
    nextnumber = ^numbers;
    numbers = record
        x: integer;
        next: nextnumber;
    end;
var
    c: integer;
    tmp, last, first: nextnumber;
begin
    last := nil;
    first := nil;
    while not seekeof do begin
        read(c);
        if first = nil then begin
            new(first);
            last := first;
        end
        else begin
            new(last^.next);
            last := last^.next;
        end;
        last^.x := c;
        last^.next := nil;
    end;
    while first <> nil do begin
        write(first^.x, ' ');
        first := first^.next
    end;
    writeln();
end.
```

И вот еще один вариант, который добавит один символ в уже имеющийся список, в конец.

```
program zadacha2;
type
        nextnumber = ^numbers;
        numbers = record
                x: integer;
                next: nextnumber;
        end;
var
        last, LIST: nextnumber;
begin
        new(LIST);
        LIST^.x := 11;
        new(LIST^.next);
        LIST^.next^.x := 22;
        new(LIST^.next^.next);
        LIST^.next^.next^.x := 33;
        
        last := LIST;
        
        while last^.next <> nil do
                last := last^.next;
        
        new(last^.next);
        last := last^.next;
        last^.x := 44;
        last^.next := nil;
        writeln(LIST^.next^.next^.next^.x);
end.
```